# Horizontal scrolling not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have this issue with a web app that we are developing, where we created a javascript datagrid.

This datagrid has a wrapper that is absolutely positioned with overflow-x auto and overflow-y: hidden, to allow it to scroll content horizontally, but not vertically. Also inside the datagrid, there is a content area div that is filled with rows of divs, for the content, which is also absolutely positioned with overflow-x hidden and overflow-y auto, allowing the content to scroll vertically.

I have tried multiple approaches suggested on the web and I am using the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` tag as well.

On all browsers and devices accept for Iphone safari, it works. Please help.

Comment: did you try overflow-x:scroll ?

Comment: Already resolved the issue, but `overflow-x:scroll` would make the content scroll able permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more investigation, using jQuery mobile with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on the section that needs to scroll horizontally, resolves the issue.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery mobile. For some reason side scrolling was not working only on iPhones in Safari, but this did the trick. Thank you!